# HTML text align property not working

Tags: html, css, text-align

I'm having problems with the "text-align" property because is not working in the following code:

```
<Titulo1>Title Text</Titulo1>
<BR>
<h1>Normal Text</h1>
```

CSS:

```
*               {font-family: Arial; color: #2D2D2D}
Titulo1         {font-size: 40px; font-weight: 900; text-align: center}
TextoNormal     {font-size: 30px; text-align: center}
```

Here is more detail: http://jsfiddle.net/jB7X3/3/

Comment: Why are you making up your own elements? That aside, though, your custom elements are defaulting to `display: inline` (for me, in Chrome), if you specify `display: block;` (or `display: inline-block` with a width larger than the content itself) it works: [demo (`display: block`)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jB7X3/5/), [demo (`display: inline-block`)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jB7X3/6/).

Comment: `Titulo1` is not a valid HTML element (neither is `TexttoNormal`). It will cause all sorts of problems if you try using it like that. This is what HTML classes and IDs are for.

Comment: What are `Titulo1` and `TextoNormal` (which I don't even see in the HTML)?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments that helped me solving the problem. I'm new in this and I was trying to create my own elements in order to know exactly what they are doing. Since is not the best practice I will use HTML existing ones, and learn more about HTML classes and IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

custom tags are `inline` element by default. you need to add `display: block` to it.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/jB7X3/16/)**

css

```
* {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #2D2D2D
}
Titulo1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-align: center;
    display: block /* add this if you wish to continue using your css */
}
TextoNormal { /* css property are not applied by content, so this will not work */
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* or a better way as in html */

<!-- or better way -->


<div>Title Text</div>

div{
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I gave me more options to solve my problem. I'm new in this and I'm trying to find out the best way to program in HTML. Anymore suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If you have any more query you are welcome to ask. You can accept this answer.